# Error with install.packages using renv|knit|rmarkdown

Tags: r, windows, curl, renv

I'm updating the renv folder from a project in order to adjust the libraries, but it seems I'm having a permission problem. After running renv::init() and trying to installing manually the remaining libraries using install.packages() I always get the message

```
Error: failed to retrieve 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/4.2/ipeadatar_0.1.6.zip' [error code 23]
1: curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
2: curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination
```

Using .libPath() I can see that the renv was created in the "AppData" hidden folder

```
1] "C:/Users/André Ferreira/AppData/Local/R/cache/R/renv/library/MacroBRA_Wrld-09789847/R-4.2/x86_64-w64-mingw32"
```

So checking my permissions, I couldn't see anything wrong. Any thoughts about this problem? The thing it's that when I open my .Rmd file and try to knit, I receive the same message *"1: curl: (23) Failure writing output to destination"*, now from rmarkdown retrieve installation, so it may be a configuration/permission problem.

Adding "C:\rtools42\usr\bin" and "C:\Program Files\R\R-4.2.1\bin" in the environment variable didn't help.

As I could see, opening an empty file from rstudio, I could use install.packages() without problem.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although this doesn't solve the problem directly, you can also instruct `renv` to use a different library path with something like:

```
# use a project-local library path
RENV_PATHS_LIBRARY = renv/library
```

in your project's `.Renviron` file. Depending on your environment, you might also consider placing the library path in an alternate location.

See https://rstudio.github.io/renv/articles/packages.html#r-cmd-build-and-the-project-library for more details.

Comment: Hi Kevin, thanks for the support. The problem was the Non ASCII character in the path. I changed the default Ren ROOT using RENV_PATHS_ROOT.

Regards,